# Can I use SELECT from dataframe instead of creating this temp table?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently using :

```
+---+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |sen                      |attributes                                                                                                                                                    |
+---+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |Stanford is good college.|[[Stanford,ORGANIZATION,NNP], [is,O,VBZ], [good,O,JJ], [college,O,NN], [.,O,.], [Stanford,ORGANIZATION,NNP], [is,O,VBZ], [good,O,JJ], [college,O,NN], [.,O,.]]|
+---+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

 I want to get above df from :
+----------+--------+--------------------+
|article_id|     sen|           attribute|
+----------+--------+--------------------+
|         1|example1|[Standford,Organi...|
|         1|example1|           [is,O,VP]|
|         1|example1| [good,LOCATION,ADP]|
+----------+--------+--------------------+
```

using :

```
df3.registerTempTable("d1")
val df4 = sqlContext.sql("select article_id,sen,collect(attribute) as attributes from d1 group by article_id,sen")
```

Is there any way that I don't have to register temp table, as while saving dataframe, it is giving lot of garbage!! Something lige df3.Select""??

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. Please review your question ! I'm voting to close it for the time being as being unclear.

Comment: @eliasah - Look at the answer, I meant something like that !!

Comment: If the given answer solved your issue, please accept it otherwise comment why it did work for you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way Spark currently has to run SQL against a dataframe is via a temporary table. However, you can add implicit methods to `DataFrame` to automate this, as we have done at [Swoop](http://swoop.com). I can't share all the code as it uses a number of our internal utilities & implicits but the core is in the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/ssimeonov/89c1e57474e38e7d05f55e5687708ee7). The importance of using unique temporary tables is that (at least until Spark 2.0) temporary tables are cluster global.

We use this approach regularly in our work, especially since there are many situations in which SQL is much simpler/easier to write and understand than the Scala DSL.

Hope this helps!